# Proving that the interference current integrated over a small cone does not depend on the angle of the cone

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, scattering, complex-numbers, scattering-cross-section

I'm studying quantum mechanical scattering and I have gotten to $$\psi=\psi_{in}+\psi_{scattering}=e^{ikrcos\theta}+f(\theta,\phi)\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}$$ and when calculating the current, i get three terms:
$$J_{in}\propto Im(\psi_{in}^*\nabla\psi_{in})$$
$$J_{out}\propto Im(\psi_{out}^*\nabla\psi_{out})$$
$$J_{scatt}\propto Im(\psi_{out}^*\nabla\psi_{in}+\psi_{in}^*\nabla\psi_{out})=Im(f^*\cos\theta e^{ikr(\cos \theta-1)}+fe^{ikr(1-\cos\theta)})$$
I now need to prove that the latter, integrated over a small cone ($\theta%$ from 0 to some small $\Theta$ and $\phi$ from 0 to $2\pi$) is equal to:
$$\iint J_{scatt}=-4\pi\frac{\hbar}{m}Im(f(\theta=0))$$
and that this small cone is the only part that contributes (see [Shankar ex. 19.5.6](https://www.physicsisbeautiful.com/resources/principles-of-quantum-mechanics/problems/19.5.6/solutions/829-solution6.pdf/jxdkLbJjAx2qGECxrDKVV3/?)) so that, using the fact that the net flux is 0, I can get to the optical theorem. But I get to the following integral:
$$\int_0^\Theta\theta e^{ikr\theta^2/2}d\theta$$
having used the approximations $\sin\theta\approx\theta$ (in the differential) and $1-\cos\theta\approx\theta^2/2$ which should result in something like $\frac{f(\theta=0)}{kr}$, but using the stationary phase method has proven hard for me (it wasn't explained to us) and by using what has been done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993001/integrals-of-rapidly-oscillating-phase-functions) I'd get $F(x)=0$ that would zero out the result. I've also tried substituting $y=\theta^2/2$ but trying to then write something like: $e^{iy}=\cos y+i\sin y$ leads me to the same zero result (by then integrating the two separately and evaluating at $\Theta$ and at 0). I've tried everything i could to get to a non-zero result but unsuccessfully. Thanks for any help you can provide :)